# calculating w coefficients for iir filter

Tags: c++, matlab

I am trying to implement an IIR filter I have designed in Matlab into a c++ program to filter out an unwanted signal from a wave file.  The fdatool in Matlab generated this C header to use (it is a bandstop filter):

```
#include "tmwtypes.h"
/* 
 * Expected path to tmwtypes.h 
 * C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2013a Student\extern\include\tmwtypes.h 
 */
const int al = 7;
const real64_T a[7] = {
     0.9915141178644,   -5.910578456199,    14.71918523779,   -19.60023964796,
      14.71918523779,   -5.910578456199,   0.9915141178644
};
const int bl = 7;
const real64_T b[7] = {
                   1,   -5.944230431733,    14.76096188047,   -19.60009655976,
      14.67733658492,   -5.877069568864,   0.9831002459245
};
```

After hours of exhausting research, I still can't figure out the proper way to use these values to determine the W values and then how to use those W values to properly calculate my Y outputs.  If anyone has any insight into the ordering these values should be used to do all these conversions, it would be a major help.

All the methods I've developed and tried to this point do not generate a valid wave file, the header values all translate correctly, but everything beyond cannot be evaluated by a media player.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this will help.
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html
Or are you looking to implement this in C++ and therefore cannot use MATLAB's builtin functions? In that case you will need to find a C++ IIR library that works similarly to filter()

Comment: I have to implement it in c++ for this project

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664686/a-c-library-for-iir-filter

Comment: I've already seen those links and none of them answer my question.  An already working c++ program might help, but I've yet to find code for a higher order IIR filter that makes any sense.  I'm really just looking for how the coefficients are used to find the W values and how those are used to find the Y(output) values rather than a functioning program

Answer (score 1):

IIR filters work this way:
Assuming an array of samples A and and array of ceof named 'c' the result array B will be:
**B[i] = (A[i] * c[0]) + (B[i-1] * c[1]) + ... + (B[n] * c[n])**

Note that only the newest element is taken from A.
This is easier to do in-place, just update A as you move along.
These filter coefs are very violent, are you sure you got them right?
The first one is also symmetrical which probably indicates it's an FIR filter.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you have a 3 pole IIR filter with the coefficients given for an Nth order implementation (as opposed to a series of 2nd order sections). Since this is a band reject (or band pass) the polynomial order is twice the pole count.

I am not sure what you mean by W values, unless you are trying to evaluate the frequency response of this filter.

To calculate the Y values, as you put it, see this link for code on implementing IIR filters. See the Nth order implementation code in particular.

http://www.iowahills.com/A7ExampleCodePage.html

BTW: I assumed these were Nth order coefficients and simulated them. I got a 10 dB notch at 0.05 Pi. Sound about right?

where
B6 = 0.9915141178644
.
.
.
b0 = 0.9915141178644

a6 = 0.9831002459245
.
.
.
a0 = 1

Also, you may want to post a question like this on:

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/